# Table button missing in Rich Text fields?

Tags: redactor

I updated to Craft 2.3 and noticed that the Table button is now missing from my Rich Text fields?

How can I get that button back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** since version 2.3.2621 Craft comes with Redactor's table plugin preinstalled again. So there's no need to do anything special, simply add it to your Redactor json config.

---

Craft 2.3 now comes with a new version of Redactor. With the release of Redactor 10 non-essential functionality was removed from Redactor's core and is now released as separate plugins.

So, to get the Table function back, you have to add the [Redactor Table plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/table/) to Craft.

You can download and save the plugin into craft/app/resources/lib/redactor/plugins/ or you can make a little Craft plugin that adds this Redactor plugin to Craft.

Comment: Because I initially thought you just had to add it to the 'buttons' part of the config... you currently add it to your Redactor config 'plugins' line, like: `plugins: ['fullscreen', 'table'],`.