# Redactor table plugin broken in Craft 2.3.2620?

Tags: redactor

I'm running Craft 2.3.2620 and installed the Redactor table plugin to `/craft/app/resources/lib/redactor/plugins`

And this is my json:

```
{
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','table','video'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen','table','video'],
    toolbarFixedBox: true,
    paragraphize: false,
    linebreaks: true
}
```

But the table button is not showing up. The video and fullscreen plugins are working fine.

Is this a bug - or is Craft's redactor implementation not compatible with their table plugin?

Comment: I think it's a bug, because my table button has dissapeared also and it was definetly working.

Comment: Thanks - I know the table was removed from the core install in 2.3 but my understanding is we should be able to still reinstall it manually. Hopefully they'll fix this soon.

Comment: I installed it manually, but it just doesn't pop-up in the redactor toolbar :( I re-installed video too and that does seem to work.

Comment: Did you guys have it working with the initial 2.3 release?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Table button missing in Rich Text fields?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/5061/45). If you've tried the solution from that thread, and still seem to be having a problem, I'd recommend contacting P&T directly at support@buildwithcraft.com.